# Can octet in IP add be a number greater than 127? cuz, each octet can only can have values in range [-128,127], also are -ve no. common in ip add?

Tags: networking, ip-address

Here is the link of website where they say we  can have numbers greater than 127 in 1st octet **[https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=433329&seqNum=5#:~:text=10-,128%E2%80%93191,-C](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=433329&seqNum=5#:%7E:text=10-,128%E2%80%93191,-C)**

Comment: Octets are simply to make it easier for humans to read, and they have no meaning to IPv4. An IPv4 address is just a 32-bit unsigned integer (a 128-bit unsigned integer for IPv6). See [this two part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) that explains IPv4 math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Octet" comes from an group of eight bits, often also called (unsigned) "byte". An octet can have one of 2^8=256 positive values, 0 through 255. An IPv4 address is actually 32 bit, usually represented as four dotted octets for human readability.

Not all values can be used in the first octet of a host address, as several are reserved for special purposes. Most significantly,

- 0 is reserved for the "current network"
- 127 is reserved for the local host's loopback address (most often only 127.0.0.1 is used)
- 224-239 are reserved for multicast (as destination address only)
- 240-255 are reserved for "future use" (which isn't going to happen); 255.255.255.255 is used as the *limited broadcast* destination address, ie. *all hosts in this network*

As a side note: the linked page talks all about *network classes* which are long obsolete and may be interesting for historical reasons only. **Network classes were obsoleted decades ago** by CIDR (RFCs 1518 & 1519).